# Raphael - how to calculate the parameters of setViewBox?

Tags: raphael

I have 2 circles on my paper, whose dimension is 1000*1000:

```
var circle1 = paper.circle(500, 500, 50);
var circle2 = paper.circle(200, 200, 25);
```

When I click `circle2`, I want to make `circle2` as the center of the view and zoom in 2 times, so `circle2` would be as big as `circle1` visually.

my code:

```
paper.setViewBox(-300, -300, 500, 500);
```

`-300` is `200-500` and `500` is `1000/2`.

I think it would work, but it doesn't. the behavior of this code is different from what I thought. How can I calculate the values properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want position of object minus 250 in this case, as 250 is half of the new coordinate setup, to figure distance to move from centre if you are zoomed. I've included a fiddle with an extra circle at lower coords to help highlight here http://jsfiddle.net/EXg5f/2/.

```
var paper = Raphael('container',1000,1000);

var circle1 = paper.circle(500, 500, 50).attr({ fill: 'red' });

var circle2 = paper.circle(200, 200, 25).attr({ fill: 'blue' });

var circle3 = paper.circle(10,10,50).attr({ fill: 'yellow' });

circle2.click( function() {
    paper.setViewBox( -50, -50, 500, 500 );
});

circle1.click( function() {
   paper.setViewBox( 250, 250, 500, 500 );
});

circle3.click( function() {
    paper.setViewBox( -240, -240, 500, 500 );
});
```